# PowerShell Job Progress Monitoring

Tags: powershell, asynchronous, background, task

Is there a way for a PowerShell job to report progress or to trigger events before it is complete?  I just started playing around with executing background jobs in PowerShell and am wondering how far I can push the capability.

Answer (score 10):

The standard "manual" way is to use the Get-Job cmdlet.  As for events, when you create a job with Start-Job, the Job object returned has a "StateChanged" event on it you can subscribe to e.g.:

```
$job = Start-Job { Get-Process; Start-Sleep -seconds 60 }
Register-ObjectEvent $job -EventName StateChanged `
    -SourceIdentifier JobStateChanged `
    -Action { Write-Host "Job $($Sender.Id) $($Sender.JobStateInfo)" }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also raise your own custom events from within a local or remote job and act on them in the local session.